# How can I get a variable already defined in drools lhs?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

I'm using drools api to define a rule like this:

```
PackageDescr pkg = DescrFactory.newPackage()
       .name("org.drools.example")
       .newRule().name("Xyz")
           .attribute("ruleflow-grou","bla")
       .lhs()
           .and()
               .pattern("Student").id( "$stu", false ).constraint("name==miko").constraint("age > 6").end()
               .not().pattern("Bar").constraint("a+b==c").end().end()
           .end()
       .end()
```

Finnally it will transfer into drl file like:

```
$stu: Studeng(name == miko, age > 6)
not Bar(a + b == c)
```

My question is if I wanna to get the '$stu' variable defined befor and to add some more constaints, like:
`$stu(grade != 2)`
how can I get it and reuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an additional constraint to Student, just chain it after the constraints you already have.

```
.pattern("Student")
  .id( "$stu", false )
  .constraint("name == \"miko\"")
  .constraint("age > 6")
  .constraint("grade != 2 ")
.end()
```

Which would generate:

```
$stu: Student( name == "miko", age > 6, grade != 2)
```

(I'm presuming that's what you're trying to do, because `$stu( grade != 2 )` is not valid syntax.)

This rule would identify any students with the name "miko" (note this is case sensitive!), have an age greater than 6, and a grade not equal to 2.

Comment: Thanks! And another question, if I wanna change to
 name == "miko" or (ang > 6 and grade != 2) how can I chain these condition together?